# Nav dinamico asp.net core sql server

Tags: sql-server, asp.net, asp.net-core

Buenas quisiera que me puedan ayudar soy nuevo en asp.net core y estoy realizando una login que si es correcto ingrese y por medio de la base de datos del procedure me devuelva el menu segun el usuario que ingresa.
Es decir en la base de datos he realizado en un store procedure que si ingresa ta usuario realice nav diferentes.
No se si estará bien lo que estoy realizando o la estructura ya que soy nuevo pero con ansias de querer mejorar.

Trate realizar en session y capturar en un dataset que se encuentra en mi modelo pero como que no sessión no se puede por el modelo.

ya que yo en asp.net c# lo que hacia es capturar la sessión y el menu dinamicamente se graficaba

lo que deseo es capturar y en el usuario donde ingresa ya se grafique dinamicamente el nav

Asi me arroja el store procedure

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
para ello ya me logre ingresar pero lo que no puedo es guardar ese menu:

**Este es mi controlador**

```
 [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Login([Bind] UsuarioDetalle user)
        {
            ModelState.Remove("username");
            ModelState.Remove("llave");
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                string LoginStatus = objUser.ValidateLogin(user);

               if (LoginStatus == "17488")
                {
                    var claims = new List<Claim>
                    {
                        new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, user.username)
                    };
                    ClaimsIdentity userIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, "login");
                    ClaimsPrincipal principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(userIdentity);
                    await HttpContext.SignInAsync(principal);
                    return RedirectToAction("UserHome", "User");

                }
                else
                {
                    TempData["UserLoginFailed"] = "Login Failed.Please enter correct credentials";
                    return View();
                }
            }
            else
                return View();
        }
```

**Este es mi modelo**

```
private static string GetConnectionString()
        {
            var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json");
            Configuration = builder.Build();
            string connectionString = Configuration["ConnectionStrings:myConString"];
            return connectionString;
        }
        string connectionString = GetConnectionString();

        public string ValidateLogin(UsuarioDetalle user)
        {
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                String llaveencriptada;
                llaveencriptada = BankPlus.Framework.Utilitarios.EncriptadorUTF.Encriptar(user.llave);
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Sp_RevIngreso", con);
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@opt", 1);    
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", user.username);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@llave", llaveencriptada);
                con.Open();
                string result = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                da.Fill(ds);
                if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    //HttpContext.Session.SetString("Menu", ds.Tables[1].Rows[0]["Menu"].ToString());

                }
                con.Close();
                return result;





            }
        }
```

Comment: ¿Lograste solucionarlo?

Comment: @fredyfx no hermano

Comment: por cierto, a qué te refieres con "modelo", se supone que en MVC, los modelos son clases, nada más.